# Error out instead of asking for passphrase with SSH

Tags: php, linux, bash, ssh

I'm writing a script that uses rsync, and I want it to error out if the SSH key has a password, telling the user to use a non-password protected key instead (as the script runs in the background).

However, none of the flags I've tried for SSH do this, and I've found nothing in the man pages.

What's the best way to disable the passphrase prompt for SSH?

Comment: Yes, that disables password authentication, not passphrases for public key authentication

Comment: Obviously, sorry didn't read carefully.  Since the user would execute the script, am I correct in assuming that the script would be able to access the user's private key (or would you find it ok to do that within the script)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the  `BatchMode` option. This will cause SSH to avoid anything that may cause a script to hang, such as password/passphrase prompts.

This example is taken directly from a similar question asked at http://www.unix.com/programming/184775-test-ssh-but-do-not-return-password-prompt.html

```
if ssh -o BatchMode=yes "$hostname" true 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "it works"
else
    echo "it's broken."
if
```

Here's an example with rsync:

```
rsync -e "ssh -o BatchMode=yes -i /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa" /path/to/test/file.txt remotehost:/path/to/test/file.txt
```

Comment: I'm already using rsync with the `-e` flag to specify the SSH command, so I'm able to add the BatchMode flag to that. Thanks!